# REST service signature using AWS

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, restkit, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am considering using AWS for a project that will have an IOS application as a client and a server side using a custom developed REST API using Java Spring. I have been reading about the need to sign all requests to AWS services using a signature version (version 4 for most services) and would like to leverage the mechanism in order to secure my REST services. There is plenty of documentation for using the REST wrappers in the AWS SDK for services such as S3 or DynamoDB, however I am having trouble getting a clear answer on how to validate signature from a custom REST API running on Elastic Bean stalk (for example a WAR deployed on Tomcat implementing Spring REST)

1) IOS client calls a REST service using RestKit (or can I use a class in Amazon SDK for IOS that I can use instead). As part of the call it specifies the token string and the AWS access key.

2) Server side, a Java program running on Tomcat on Elastic Bean stalk, receives the REST call and  processes it by first validating the signature. If the signature corresponds to the re computed signature then allow the request, otherwise reject it.

Could anyone point me into the right direction in terms of what is available in the AWS SDK for ObjC and Java to do this REST signature validation (again not using pre boxed services such as S3)?

Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question and a very popular feature request from our customers.  As of today, there is no AWS API to validate an AWS Access Key / Secret Key based signatures for your custom web services.

However, everything AWS does is based on customer feedback and your feedback helps to setup our development priorities.  We are hearing that requirement a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was much appreciated. What would be your opinion for the following: I would like to leverage S3 to store photos and DynamoDB for user profile keeping, thereby using the Amazon SDK methods (after authentication via Cognito). I can use the Amazon SDK to do that and the signed requests will be transparent to my application code. For the custom REST services call, what would you recommend in terms of security, OAuth2? What do most of the AWS customer do in this regard?

Comment: The most scalable way to design an application using S3 or DynamoDB is to let the client directly read / write to the S3 and DynamoDB backend using the JavaScript (for web app) or iOS/Android SDK (for mobile apps). This would leverage the AWS backend and offload your server side infrastructure. When an API is needed I would make it stateless and would just accept the AK/SK generated by Cognito on the client side to ensure your API runs with your client's privileges. When more priviledges are required, EC2 roles are a clean solution.